# My scrollbar is not working with mouse's scroller

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, mouse

I have reused the code.
I am trying to scroll this frame and the scrollbar is working but
I want it to be scrolled using the scroller of mouse.
What should I do?
I want it to be scrolled vertically only.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root['bg'] = 'wheat'


frame_container=Frame(root, width = 1000)
frame_container['bg'] = 'wheat'
canvas_container=Canvas(frame_container, width = 1000)
canvas_container['bg'] = 'wheat'


frame2=Frame(canvas_container, width = 1000)
frame2['bg'] = 'wheat'

scrollbar_tk = Scrollbar(frame_container, 
orient="vertical",command=canvas_container.yview)#, 
yscrollcommand=scrollbar_tk.set
 # will be visible if the frame2 is to to big for the canvas
canvas_container.create_window((0,0),window=frame2,anchor='nw')


naan = IntVar()
roti=IntVar()
dal=IntVar()
manchurian = IntVar()
makhani=IntVar()
masala_bhindi = IntVar()
chole = IntVar()
rajma = IntVar()
shahi_panneer = IntVar()
kadahi_paneer = IntVar()
masala_gobhi = IntVar()
allo_gobhi = IntVar()
matar_paneer = IntVar()
menu_roti = "Tava Roti             25 ₹/piece"
menu_dal = "Dal                       80 ₹/bowl"
menu_makhani = "Dal Makhni          110 ₹/bowl"
menu_naan = "Naan                    50 ₹/piece"
menu_manchurian = "Manchurian         110 ₹/plate"     
menu_shahi_panneer = "Shahi paneer      110₹/bowl"
menu_kadahi_paneer = "Kadhai paneer     150/bowl"
menu_masala_gobhi = "Masala gobhi      130₹/bowl"
menu_allo_gobhi = "Aloo gobhi          120₹/bowl" 
menu_matar_paneer = "Matar paneer      135₹/bowl"
menu_masala_bhindi = "Masala bhindi     110₹/bowl"
menu_chole = "Chole                 100₹/bowl"  
menu_rajma = "Rajama              150₹/bowl"
menu_chaap = "Chaap                125₹/bowl"
menu_aloo_parntha = "Aloo parantha     35₹/peice" 
menu_cheele = "Cheele                55₹/peice "

listItems = [menu_roti,menu_dal,menu_makhani, menu_naan, 
menu_manchurian, menu_shahi_panneer,
             menu_kadahi_paneer, menu_masala_gobhi, 
menu_allo_gobhi, menu_matar_paneer, menu_masala_bhindi, 
menu_chole, menu_rajma, menu_chaap, menu_aloo_parntha, 
 menu_cheele]


Title = Label(frame2, text = "                Food Items         
Prices         Quantities", fg = 'red', bg = 'wheat', font= 
("arial", 30))
Title.grid()
for item in listItems:
    label = Label(frame2,text=item, fg = 'yellow', bg = 
'wheat', font=("arial", 30))
    label.grid(column=0, row=listItems.index(item)+1)


q_roti = Entry(frame2, font=("arial",20), textvariable = roti, 
fg="Black", width=10)
q_roti.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
q_dal = Entry(frame2, font=("arial",20), textvariable = dal, 
fg="black", width=10)
q_dal.grid(column = 1, row = 2)
q_makhani = Entry(frame2, font=("arial",20), textvariable = 
makhani, fg="black", width=10)
q_makhani.grid(column = 1, row = 3)
q_naan = Entry(frame2, font=("arial",20), textvariable = naan, 
fg="black", width=10)
q_naan.grid(column = 1, row = 4)
q_manchurian = Entry(frame2,font=("arial",20), textvariable = 
manchurian, fg="black", width=10)
q_manchurian.grid(column = 1, row = 5)
q_shahi_panneer = Entry(frame2, font=("arial",20), textvariable 
= shahi_panneer, fg="black", width=10)
q_shahi_panneer.grid(column = 1, row = 6)
q_kadahi_panneer = Entry(frame2, font=("arial",20), 
textvariable = kadahi_paneer, fg="black", width=10)
q_kadahi_panneer.grid(column = 1, row = 7)
q_masala_gobhi = Entry(frame2, font=("arial",20), textvariable 
= masala_gobhi, fg="black", width=10)
q_masala_gobhi.grid(column = 1, row = 8)
q_allo_gobhi = Entry(frame2, font=("arial",20), textvariable = 
allo_gobhi, fg="black", width=10)
q_allo_gobhi.grid(column = 1, row = 9)
q_matar_panneer = Entry(frame2, font=("arial",20), textvariable 
= matar_paneer, fg="black", width=10)
q_matar_panneer.grid(column = 1, row = 10)
q_masala_bhindi = Entry(frame2, font=("arial",20), textvariable 
= masala_bhindi, fg="black", width=10)
q_masala_bhindi.grid(column = 1, row = 11)
q_cholle = Entry(frame2,font=("arial",20), textvariable = 
chole, fg="black", width=10)
q_cholle.grid(column = 1, row = 12)
q_rajma = Entry(frame2,font=("arial",20), textvariable = rajma, 
fg="black", width=10)
q_rajma.grid(column = 1, row = 13)

frame2.update() # update frame2 height so it's no longer 0 ( 
height is 0 when it has just been created )
canvas_container.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_tk.set, 
scrollregion="0 0 0 %s" % frame2.winfo_height()) # the 
scrollregion 
mustbe the size of the frame inside it,
                                                                                                            
#in this case "x=0 y=0 width=0 height=frame2height"
                                                                                                            
#width 0 because we only scroll verticaly so don't mind about 
the width.
canvas_container.grid(column = 1, row = 0)

scrollbar_tk.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky='ns')


frame_container.grid()#.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

root.mainloop()
```

Sorry for this code. This is not much understandable but maybe it is sufficient for someone of my level. please someone give me some advices to improve my skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<MouseWheel>` virtual event to scroll the canvas and ultimately the frame.

```
canvas_container.create_window((0,0),window=frame2,anchor='nw')
def _on_mousewheel(event):
    canvas_container.yview_scroll(-1*int(event.delta/120), "units")   
canvas_container.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", _on_mousewheel)
```

Comment: Thank you Sujay I can't vote up this answer cuz I only have 9 reputation!! But I have marked this answer correct.

Comment: No problem @Hashtag3